# Grafana Panel Plugin Load data on demand (click event)

Tags: grafana

I am working on a customized panel plugin where I need to show data and provide a drill down functionality. My environment would be

React Panel
Grafana 6.5.3
InfluxDb as datasource
What I want to achieve is

Initial set of data will be loaded from influx query (That part is pretty much clear how to do).
The customized panel have some clickable items and on click I need to load additional data (based on selection), I am not sure how this part can be achieved and what is best way to communicate with data source (influxDb in my case) from panel plugin. I see eventBus 1, perhaps this is the way to communicate with outer world, but couldn’t find any significant help from documentation.
Any sort of help/pointer is appreciated, or example opensource plugin which is already doing such stuff.